# Alternating Series Sum to Infinity Question

Tags: calculus, power-series

[Question 5bii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrvRR.png)

I have trouble with question 5b ii.

So I found the partial sum to be 0.333, 0.111, 0.269, 0.148,

0.246. However, the question asks the series to be less than 0.25.

I do not know how I can explain the answer in the test.
How can I answer this after finding the partial sum? 
Can someone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: __Hint:__ The series is an alternating series where $|a_i|$ is decreasing, hence the limit is bounded between consecutive partial sums, like $0.148$ and $0.246$ (assuming your calculations are correct.

Comment: So why is it bounded to consecutive partial sums when the series is monotonic decreasing? :o